# python response.text cant decode

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, encoding, request

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://site"

paramsRequest = {

}

headersRequest = {
"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
}

response = requests.get(url, params=paramsRequest, headers=headersRequest)

file_path = 'D:/tempfiles/file.txt'

with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(response.text)

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file_content = file.read()

print(file_content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 
print(soup.prettify())

response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding
print(response.text)
```

try this code... but got answer like this:

�� ��9�?���/����@�[��08�/��)�#�h4�f���A��ѸQ(M{�B���������4�k(i76���r0�
;.�b>�s�$g�& 8��x�G7E��88&�s�jܦ��+�7��&)���1�������� )�~,�d���� }c
j������?�$�e�T��K�K�4��c�v:�K���)�TJ
�X����H5�é�ߏ�r)�:����_���

[image]

I tried

1. response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding
2. soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') print(soup.prettify())

upd: FULL Request=

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*

Accept-Language:en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

X-Lead-Source: website

Connection: keep-alive

Cookie: *ew_source*=widget

Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors

Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

TE: trailers

answer:json

Comment: It looks like your link is returning a binary file, i.e. image, binary, etc. That isn't human readable. What were you expecting the link to return?

Comment: For starters, you need to check `Content-Type` on the HTTP Response. Adding it as a header for the request will generally be ignored. Additionally, without knowing the URL you are requesting we can't do much more than guesswork. If you provided the HTTP Response Headers that should be enough to determine how to see the results as text (if it is actually textual content).

Comment: can you provide the url, so I can test it, bcs its working for me when I test it on other pages

Comment: In such cases, you can try specifying the encoding manually to ensure that the response is properly decoded. Here's how you can modify your code to handle the encoding issue  response.encoding = 'utf-8'

Comment: upd: added full request. In browser I got correct json, but in python script I cant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused when I got binary file in python script, but same request in firefox mozilla works correct.

So I removed header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br", and now it works correct. thx everyone